# Can we apply Gauss's law for the $D$ field here?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Consider a thick spherical shell half filled with linear dielectric liquid (the other half is vacuum). Also assume there is a charge q placed at the center of the shell.

[image]

I am wondering if it is possible to use Gauss's law for $D$: $\int \vec{D} \cdot d\vec{a} = Q_{free}$  to find D in this case? I think the answer is no because there is nonzero curl of P ($\nabla \times \vec{P} \ne \vec{0}$) on the radial sides of the dielectric hemisphere. Is that right? If so, how to find D?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

If you use differential forms of the principle, remember to use it in regions of space where the physical quantities are regular enough.

Between two regular regions of space, you may use jump conditions at discontinuities.

Anyway, I'm not 100% sure you can exploit an axial symmetry condition to analytically find the field $\mathbf{d}(\mathbf{r})$, since the structure of the system is not axial symmetric.

Comment: Can you give me further justification on why I can still use D Gauss law even though there are areas with nonzero $\nabla \times \vec{D}$?

Comment: I'd say that how Nature works, if we trust in Maxwell's equations as fundamental principles in electromagnetism. The equation $\Phi_{\partial V} ( \mathbf{d}) = Q_V^{int}$, i.e. the electric charge inside the volume $V$, $Q_V^{int}$, equals the flux of the field $\mathbf{d}$ across the boundary $\partial V$ of the volume $V$, holds because it agrees with experimental measurements, and it's usually taken as a principle of the theory.